# How do I test whether a sequence is infinite in F#?

Tags: f#

If I have a sequence that gets generated by a recursive function, like so:

```
let rec genConst t = seq { yield t ; yield! genConst (t) }
let inf = genConst 1
```

how can I test whether the length of inf is infinite or not?

Comment: If it never returns, it's a safe bet it's infinite (or close to it).

Comment: Isn't this the core of the undecidability problem?

Comment: @Chaitanya - Yes, this is the same as asking if this code will complete or not - which has been proved to be unprovable. However, specific examples can be shown to complete - it's just impossible to generalize.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what sort of answer you're looking for here. If you mean to ask whether there's some attribute or property of a sequence that identifies it as infinite without attempting to enumerate said sequence, then the answer is 'no'.

Comment: This is not so much an F# question as a computer science question; you may want to start here: [*The undecidable problem in computability theory* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem#The_undecidable_problem_in_computability_theory).

Comment: If you figure this out, let me know :-) I know a couple of people in our research lab and in Microsoft Research who would be _very_ interested in the answer to this! That said, you could probably do some reflection magic to detect that this particular case is infinite, but that won't solve the general problem.

Comment: Trolls on Stackoverflow.  <sigh>

Comment: Thanks gents. I didn't have the halting problem in mind:) but rather the specific case of a simple recursive function like the one above. But from the answers (i.e. Tomas's) I'm getting the impression I'm in way over my head.

Comment: In case of simple (structural) recursion, it is often quite easy to _prove_ that a function/sequence terminates. You could translate the function to [Coq](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/Basics.html#lab18). If Coq accepts the definition, its termination is proven.

Answer (score 2):

It is fundamentally impossible.
F# sequence is essentially a <s>wrapper over</s> synonym  of `IEnumerable<'T>`.
Neither `IEnumerable<'T>` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)   nor `IEnumerator` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) provide any means for retrieving its length.

UPD thanks @svick for an important correction.

Comment: `seq<'T>` is not really a wrapper for `IEnumerable<'T>`, it's just a synonym for it.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps your particular case, you could define a wrapper type that marks a sequence infinite:

```ml
type InfiniteSeq<'T> = private Infinite of seq<'T> with
  interface seq<'T> with
    member x.GetEnumerator() = let (Infinite s) = x in s.GetEnumerator()
  interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
    member x.GetEnumerator() = let (Infinite s) = x in s.GetEnumerator() :> _

module Seq =
  let infinite source = Infinite source

let rec genConst t = seq { yield t ; yield! genConst (t) } |> Seq.infinite

let firstFive = genConst 1 |> Seq.take 5
```

You get polymorphism with `seq<_>` and the type denotes the additional behavior.